# How to replace a codebehind method with an aspx method using ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp:hyperlink control as part of a gridview template. The code in the aspx page is given below:

```
asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkEdit" ToolTip="Edit article" NavigateUrl='<%# GetUrl(Eval("ID").ToString(), Eval("CategoryID").ToString()) %>' ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif"
```

The NavigateUrl value is obtained from the codebehind method GetUrl(string, string). The code works fine and is as follows:

```
protected string GetUrl(string id, string categoryID)
{
    var CategoryID = string.Empty;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["CatID"]))
    {
        CategoryID = Request.QueryString["CatID"].ToString();
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryID))
    {
        CategoryID = categoryID;
    }
    return "~/TBSArticles/WriteOrEditArticle.aspx?ID=" + id + "&CatID=" + CategoryID;
}
```

I want to replace the code behind method by using a ternary operator within the aspx page. I tried something like below, but didn't work:

```
asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkEdit" ToolTip="Edit article" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/TBSArticles/WriteOrEditArticle.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID")  + "&CatID=" + Eval(this.Request.QueryString["CatID"].ToString()) != ""? this.Request.QueryString["CatID"] : Eval("CategoryID")) %>' ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have many thinks to do is better to use a function on code behind to call, and avoid issues and bugs from the difficult of the one line code. So you call the function as:

```
asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#GetHyperLinkUrl(Container.DataItem)%>' ID="lnkEdit" ToolTip="Edit article"
```

and write it on code behind  as

```
protected string GetHyperLinkUrl(object oItem)
{
    StringBuilder cbRet = new StringBuilder();

    cbRet.Append( Page.ResolveUrl("~/TBSArticles/WriteOrEditArticle.aspx?ID=") );
    cbRet.Append( DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "ID") );
    cbRet.Append(  "&CatID=" );

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["CatID"]))  
        cbRet.Append( DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "CategoryID") );
    else
        cbRet.Append( DataBinder.Eval(oItem, Request.QueryString["CatID"].ToString()) );

    return cbRet.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you used was cleaner and I prefer that.

I replicated your issue and I think you just have an extra closing bracket

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "~/TBSArticles/WriteOrEditArticle.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID")  + "&CatID=" + Eval(this.Request.QueryString["CatID"].ToString()) != ""? this.Request.QueryString["CatID"] : Eval("CategoryID")) %>'
```

CORRECTION: removed the last Eval("CategoryID") bracket

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "~/TBSArticles/WriteOrEditArticle.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID")  + "&CatID=" + Eval(this.Request.QueryString["CatID"].ToString()) != ""? this.Request.QueryString["CatID"] : Eval("CategoryID") %>'
```